# Partially ordered set with mixed-integer variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I have a finite set of vectors $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with mixed-integer components (let's say $n_c$ and $n_i$, with $n = n_c + n_i$). I was wondering whether $\mathcal{S}$ is always partially ordered, e.g., under lexicographic order, or I do need something more.

Any reference on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are "mixed integer components"? $\mathbb R^n$ is partially ordered with lexicographic order, so your $S$ is of course also partially ordered. If the lexicographical ordering is useful to you is of course another question.

Comment: @Ingix any vector in $\mathcal{S}$ has $n_c$ components lying in $\mathbb{R}^{n_c}$ and $n_i$ components in $\mathbb{Z}^{n_i}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But as I said already, $S$ is partially ordered by lexicographic order, your explanation doesn't change that. If you say why you apparently need the partial order property ("or do I need something more"), it may be possible to say if it helps you in your problem.